# How to display a thumbnail of a geotagged photo in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, photos, geotag, thumbnail

I am using Qgis 3.10 on windows. I have created a shapefile of geotagged photos using the 'Import photo's' plugin. This gives me a map with an icon at the location of each photo. The attribute table has a filepath to the location of the photos and a relative filepath.

[image]

I want to replace that icon with a thumbnail of the photo. I have found some questions about this but none of the answers tell me fully how to do it step by step.
I have changed the symbology to 'Raster image marker'. I think I need to use 'Data defined override' to point to the image location somehow, but can't work out how.

[image]

I need a simple method that can be used by lots of people in an organisation that only occassionaly use GIS.

Comment: You say, in the attribute table there is the path to the image on your server. So, what else would you need? (despite a clever scaling factor, but that is another issue)

Answer (score 3):

like Eric already said, just select the right field: Click on the yellow spot (datadefined override) and select in your case "Path" - which should have the path + image name. dont't forget to increase the size of your raster fill icon to see anything. see picture below. By the way - there is also a processing tool doing the same thing: Import geotagged photos

[image]